# Why won't MYSQL procedure properly iterate new ROWS in TABLE using WHILE statement?

Tags: mysql

I am creating this basic procedure using MySQL Workbench to accept a single input parameter.
The table "unique_days" has a single PRIMARY KEY column called "dayid" which currently has a single ROW with a value of 1.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dayid_iteration;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dayid_iteration(maxdate_final INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxdate_current INT;
    SET @maxdate_current = (SELECT (MAX(dayid) + 1) FROM unique_days);
    DELETE FROM unique_days WHERE dayid > 1;
    
    WHILE (maxdate_current > maxdate_final) DO
        INSERT INTO unique_days (dayid) VALUES (maxdate_current);
        SET maxdate_current = (maxdate_current+1);
    END WHILE;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The procedure is then called with an integer parameter.

```
CALL dayid_iteration(11);
```

The variables are setting properly because I can run a select statement with the variable and it shows the correct new value. The deletion of dayid > 1 also works (Tested by manually adding additional rows, and then running procedure). However, I can't seem to get the WHILE statement to insert new rows with the value provided.

Any help is much appreciated. I searched multiple other questions, and countless forums, but everything looks like it should be working.

[image: Result from calling the procedure]

I am expecting the code to CREATE 9 ROWS for a total of 10 ROWS.

The following is included just so you can see the starting values of the table.

```
SELECT * FROM unique_days;
```

[image: Starting result from running "SELECT * FROM unique_days;"]

Comment: Your test is `maxdate_current > maxdate_final` but you're incrementing maxdate_current: `SET maxdate_current = (maxdate_current+1);` so how does this WHILE loop ever end? I'm almost sure you want `maxdate_current < maxdate_final` (or `<=`)

Comment: @barrycarter Hello, I'm very sorry for the delay in response. I fell asleep after posting the question, and then wasn't available yesterday.  Thank you for taking the time to look at it! You were absolutely correct that the greater than was backwards, and I'm ashamed I missed that after looking at it for 2 days.  That said, I did flip it correctly, and the WHILE statement still has "0 row(s) affected."

I am so baffled why this isn't working...

"WHILE (maxdate_current < maxdate_final) DO" has 0 rows affected.

Comment: I still haven't solved this, but using a hard coded value of 11 does cause the desired result. I must be doing something wrong with receiving the parameter into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this question, the following code functions correctly. The input variable on the parameter was not setting properly. Once the parameter had "IN" placed in front of the variable name, it correctly received the parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dayid_iteration(IN maxdate_final INT)
```

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dayid_iteration;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dayid_iteration(IN maxdate_final INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxdate_current INT;
    SET maxdate_current = (SELECT (MAX(dayid) + 1) FROM unique_days);
    
    WHILE (maxdate_current <= maxdate_final) DO
        INSERT INTO unique_days (dayid) VALUES (maxdate_current);
        SET maxdate_current = (maxdate_current+1);
    END WHILE;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL dayid_iteration(1000);
```

This call procedure now properly works.

```
CALL dayid_iteration(1000);
```